# What are the differences between Select2 and selectize?

Tags: jquery-plugins, html-select, jquery-select2

What are the differences between Select2 and selectize? I was using select2 from a long time, but recently known 1 more plugin called selectize. I want to know which 1 is better than other.

Comment: You are not allowed to take an existing question and change it to a completely new question to circumvent a question ban.

Comment: @BoltClock, This is 0 answered question & 0 voted, it shows that it is useless question for community at all, so It does't effect anyone if I change it. I think what I updated is more appropriate and is important one to discuss.